# Copy MS Access table to different MS Access

Tags: vb.net, copy

Please help; I wanted to copy an MS Access table and its data into another table at different MS Access database. I came across hundreds of access databases which has to be reformatted, I decided to write VB.Net code and format one table so that it can be copy to other hundreds instant of formatting one by one.

Here is my trial code:

```
Dim cmdCreate as New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [Hierarchy] IN "c:\hierarchy.pdb" FROM [Hierarchy]  WHERE 0=1",  con1)

cmdCreate.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Note: con1 datasource is deference with table2 directory.

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain what happens when you try to run that code.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your reply. an OleDbException was Unhandled error was pop out like this  "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Answer (score 0):

here is a function in Access you can put a loop around with appropriate args.  The dbSource and dbTarget are the full path names.

```
Public Function ExportTableToDatabase (TableName As String, dbSource As String, dbTarget As String, Optional Append As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    If Append Then
        'The sql will use APPEND TO TABLE syntax
        SQL = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " IN """ & dbTarget & """ " _
            & "SELECT " & TableName & ".* FROM " & TableName & " IN """ & dbSource & """ "
    
    Else
        'The sql will use CREATE TABLE syntax
        SQL = "SELECT " _
            & TableName & ".* INTO " & TableName & " " _
            & "IN """ & dbTarget & """ " _
            & "FROM " & TableName & " " _
            & "IN """ & dbSource & """ "
    
    End If
    
    db.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

    ExportTableToDatabase = True
    
Cleanup:
    set db = nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Trap:
    msgbox Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Cleanup
    Resume
End Function
```